# How to use ESLint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, formatting, eslint

Basically i have installed ESLint from here

```
http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started
```

.eslintrs.json looks like this

```
    {
    "extends": ["eslint:recommended",
                "angular",
                "plugin:jasmine/recommended"],
    "installedESLint": true,
    "plugins": [
        "standard",
        "promise",
        "jasmine"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "strict": 0,
        "indent": [2, 4],
        "quotes": [2, "single"],
        "no-unused-vars": 1,
        "no-underscore-dangle": 1
    },
    "env": {
        "jasmine": true
    },
    "globals": {
        "navigator": true
    }
}
```

Basically there are few `.js` files i need to check with the extra spaces and unnecessary lines. So did

```
eslint myfile.js
```

This is what i am getting
    Automatic Configuration failed.  No files were able to be parsed.

How to use ESLint to remove unnecessary spaces and lines for a js files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration file should be `.eslintrc.*`, or simply `.eslintrc`

http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

> Configuration Files - use a JavaScript, JSON or YAML file to specify
>   configuration information for an entire directory and all of its
>   subdirectories. This can be in the form of an .eslintrc.* file or an
>   eslintConfig field in a package.json file, both of which ESLint will
>   look for and read automatically, or you can specify a configuration
>   file on the command line.

**Edit:**

You can append `--fix` to ask ESLint to auto-fix problems found.

eg.

```
eslint myfile.js mydir --fix
```

Comment: This part i understood.. Basically ESLint wil look for and read automatically the JS file did not understand...  It should look into my js files? and do formatting of removing spaces and lines

Comment: is it like `eslint myfile.js \proj\www\js\ --fix` ?

Comment: `mydir` is a path to directory

Answer (score 0):

That means you did not configured the path where ESLINT will check your code.

GO to your_project\node_modules.bin folder, run eslint --init then you will need to answer to these questions :

- ? How would you like to configure ESLint?
- ? Which file(s), path(s), or glob(s) should be examined?
- ? What format do you want your config file to be in?
- ? Are you using ECMAScript 6 features?
- ? Are you using ES6 modules?
- ? Where will your code run? Browser, Node
- ? Do you use CommonJS?
- ? Do you use JSX?

Be careful about the second question to do not have a "No files were able to be parsed" error